# Trying to use append, when I try to print the list created by append it says "None"

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, scipy, append

I am very new to Python and programming in general, having only done it for about one month.

Hi, I have created some code which reads in data, and via a for loop, it changes which column in the data it reads for the y-variables, whilst the x-variable stays the same. It then extracts one of the parameters for a fit I have applied to the data (mu/mean of a gaussian+line fit), and then uses this mean to calculate a velocity for said fixed x-variables and the column of data for the y-variable and then this velocity is stored in a list called "velocity_database". All of this is within the for loop. Outside of the for loop, I want it to print the list so I can see all the velocities. I need to use these velocities later for more analysis.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np #importing necessary packages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
e=np.exp
spectral_data=np.loadtxt(r'C:/Users/Sidharth/Documents/Computing Labs/Project 1/Halpha_spectral_data.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=2) #importing data file
v_list = [] # will store the velocities's in this list
for i in range(1, 30): # each iteration i gets a different value, starting with 1 and end with 30
    x = spectral_data[:, 0]
    y = spectral_data[:, i]
    plt.scatter(x,y) #produce scatter plot
    plt.title('Observation 1')
    plt.ylabel('Intensity (arbitrary units)')
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength (m)')
    m,c=np.polyfit(x,y2,deg=1) #fits a linear model to the data, with m = slope and c = intercept
    plt.plot(x,y,'*')
    plt.plot(x,c+m*x,'-') #plots the fit

    print('The slope and intercept of the regression is,', m,c)
    m_best=m
    c_best=c
    def fit_gauss(x,a,mu,sig,m,c):
        gaus = a*sp.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sig**2))
        line = m*x+c
        return gaus + line

    initial_guess=[160,7.1*10**-7,0.2*10**-7,m_best,c_best]
    po,po_cov=sp.optimize.curve_fit(fit_gauss,x,y,initial_guess)

#print("The parameters")
#print(po)
#print('The covariance matrix')
#print(po_cov)

    print("The signal parameters are")
    print(" Gaussian amplitude = %.1f +/- %.1f" %(po[0],sp.sqrt(po_cov[0,0])))
    print(" mu = %.1e +/- %.1e"%(po[1],sp.sqrt(po_cov[1,1])))
    print(" Gaussian width (sigma) = %.1f +/- %.1f"%(po[2],sp.sqrt(po_cov[2,2])))
    print("and the background estimate is")
    print(" m = %.2f +/- %.2f"%(po[3],sp.sqrt(po_cov[3,3])))
    print(" c = %.0f +/- %.0f"%(po[4],sp.sqrt(po_cov[4,4])))

    plt.plot(x,fit_gauss(x,po[0],po[1],po[2],po[3],po[4]),label='Fit results') #plots the fit just to confirm by eye whether the fit is okay
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    mu_calc=po[1]
    print("mu is",mu_calc)
    light_speed=3*10**8
    expect_lambda_square=(656.28*10**-9)**2
    v=-1*((expect_lambda_square*light_speed)-((mu_calc**2)*(light_speed)))/(expect_lambda_square+(mu_calc**2))
    print("v is",v, "m/s")
    velocity_database=v_list.append(v) # store velocity of the galaxy at the end of the growing list of velocities
print("The velocities are",velocity_database)
```

The console response gives me all the values of the mean/mu and the velocity for each column of data, but when I try and print the list (velocity_database) at the end, it says:

```
The velocities are None
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is `v_list` and I dont understand why you try to print `velocity_database` which is only defined inside the for loop and must be `None` as `list.append()` does not return anything. From how your code is setup I am guessing that you actually want to print out `v_list` to which you append all of the values.

Comment: Yeah, looking back at it now, it's just silly. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `append()` method appends the input to the existing list(`v_list`), and it doesn't return anything, or it returns None.
So the data you want is probably `v_list.`